# Accessing SQL from Entity Framework Core Queries in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In a post in the last week or so, someone made reference to a post: http://rion.io/2016/10/19/accessing-entity-framework-core-queries-behind-the-scenes-in-asp-net-core/

The blog outlined using internals of EF to show the generated SQL for a given EF query. Having a tool like this is invaluable, and will help my EF dev team to write better code. However, as it uses internal and unsupported code, it will not build using EF 2.1.4. The reference to RelationalQueryModelVisitor is now gone, and the code will not build.

I am using using .net core 2.1 as well.

Is there another or similar approach available?

Thanks.

Comment: In that article, one of the comments points to this: https://gist.github.com/nour-s/3bbf9b2588faa6b849393639a8b39757

Comment: @GabrielLuci  Yes, agreed. The reference you provided has the issue.

Comment: So did you try that one? People in the comments claim that it works with 2.1

Comment: The original post, as well as my previous response to you indicate this is the case. Do you have a different result?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me. The link I gave has different code than the article you mention in your original post.

Comment: And please leave the link that I edited in your question. URLs are meant to be clickable.

Comment: The link you gave provides code which does not compile. In fact, it has the same issue. As well as a few more. So, this show that you have not invested any effort in identifying the solution. Please read the post again, and feel free to provide an answer with value. No one here has time to deal with posts which are inapplicable to current code. Thank you.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that we were referring to the same thing before I invested any effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use the class in [this link](https://gist.github.com/nour-s/3bbf9b2588faa6b849393639a8b39757), which does work in .NET Core 2.1. Yes, I know you said you tried it, but I just tried it and it worked, so there must be something else going wrong in your project. Tell us the compiler error you are getting and we can help further.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a new ASP.NET Core project and made sure it's targetting .NET Core 2.1.
2. Added `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version 2.1.4 from NuGet.
3. Created an `IQueryableExtensions` class and pasted the code.

It compiles.

The `RelationalQueryModelVisitor` class does still exist in .NET Core 2.1. The [documentation shows it is still there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.relationalquerymodelvisitor?view=efcore-2.1) (notice the "Entity Framework Core 2.1" in the top left of the docs) and the [current source code on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/779d43731773d59ecd5f899a6330105879263cf3/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/RelationalQueryModelVisitor.cs) still shows it there.

Answer (score 0):

Would using their logging functionality be sufficient?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging

```
public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = new LoggerFactory(new[] {new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)});

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
        .UseSqlServer(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational nuget package.